# How to preserve the file-input in play with previous selected file, when validation fails?

Tags: forms, validation, file-upload, playframework-2.0, multipartform-data

Tried this on play 2.1.1
Have two fields: picture (input file) , description (input text), like this:

```
@(pictureForm: Form[FileUpload]) 

@import helper._

@form(action = routes.Uploader.uploadSimple, 'enctype -> "multipart/form-data") {


  @helper.inputFile(pictureForm("picture"))

  @helper.inputText(pictureForm("description"))

  <button type="submit" > submit </button>

}
```

Marked description as @required in the fileupload-pojo. If the validation fails ( User gave no description) and the bad-request is thrown, the input-file selection, that the User selected before, vanishes.

My Controller works like this:

```
public static Result upload() {

    Map<String, String> formData = new HashMap<String, String>();

    MultipartFormData body = request().body().asMultipartFormData();
    Map<String, String[]> result = body.asFormUrlEncoded();

    FilePart picture = body.getFile("picture");

    if (picture != null) {
        formData.put("contentType", picture.getContentType());
        File file = picture.getFile();
        formData.put("picture", file.toString());
    }

    formData.put("description",result.get("description")[0]);               

    Form<FileUpload> uploadForm = Form.form(FileUpload.class).bind(formData);

    if (uploadForm.hasErrors()) {
        return badRequest(upload.render(uploadForm));
    } else {
        return ok("Got picture uploaded");
    }
}
```

I don't want the user to fill out the picture-selection because of one error of another field for usability purposes. The validation occurs in the FileUpload-class because i wanted it to be separated:

```
package models;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import play.data.validation.ValidationError;

public class FileUpload {

public String contentType;
public String description;
public String picture;

public List<ValidationError> validate() {

    List<ValidationError> valErrors = new ArrayList<ValidationError>();

    if (description == null || description.isEmpty())
        valErrors.add(new ValidationError("description",
                "Give a description."));

    if (contentType != null && !contentType.isEmpty()) {
        if (!(contentType.equals("image/jpeg") || contentType.equals("image/png"))) 
            valErrors.add(new ValidationError("picture",
                            "Wrong format."));
    }   else {
            valErrors
            .add(new ValidationError("picture",
                    "No picture chosen."));
        }

    return valErrors.isEmpty() ? null : valErrors;

}
```

}

I need to get the path of the selection in the input file. How do i define FileUpload to connect it with the input-file field? My controller takes the multipart-data and i can get the file, but i throw a badrequest with the validations in case of an error.

I hope this kind of makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of solving it (roughly):

Add an optional path to your form:

```
public class FileUpload {
   public String path;
   //...
}
```

Now when you parse the form, you add the path of the uploaded file in your form:

```
FilePart picture = body.getFile("picture");

if (picture != null) {
    //...
    formData.put("path", picture.getRelativePath());
}
```

To make sure this path is send back to the server between requests, you could put it into a hidden input:

```
@form(action = routes.Uploader.uploadSimple, 'enctype -> "multipart/form-data") {
    @*...*@
    <input type="hidden" name="path" value="@pictureForm.data.get("path")" />
}
```

Finally, when validating the form, instead of checking if there's an uploaded picture you must now also include a case where the picture is already uploaded and the path of the uploaded picture is in `path`.

To increase usability you could also hide the file input when there's a path specified in `pictureForm`.